# Difference between Seq.map and Seq.collect in F#

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

In F#, what is the difference between functions "Seq.collect" and "Seq.map"? They seem equivalent from the description on MSDN.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Seq.collect` will first map each sequence element to a **new sequence** and flatten this sequences into a single one.

`Seq.map` will just map each element to a **new element**.

Comment: Thanks, I should have looked at the function signatures more closely.

Answer (score 32):

If you know LINQ, the following comparison may be useful:

F#: `Seq.map`, LINQ: `Select`

F#: `Seq.collect`, LINQ: `SelectMany`

Comment: Thanks, your tip led me to this page which really helped:

http://team.interknowlogy.com/blogs/danhanan/archive/2008/10/10/use-linq-s-selectmany-method-to-quot-flatten-quot-collections.aspx